Why is hyclate only associated with doxycycline?
Hyclate (hydrochloride hemiethanolate hemihydrate) formulation is only associated with the antibiotic doxycycline.
I asked my question from Copilot and this is its answer:

Other drugs may not use the hyclate anion because they don't require the same solubility and stability enhancements, or they might have different chemical structures and properties that necessitate alternative formulations.

From this I hypothesized that the hyclate can form intermolecular bonds that can only be attached to doxycycline.
But I couldn't find any sources to test my hypothesis.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9499/what-is-the-difference-between-doxycycline-hcl-and-doxycycline-hyclate

TL:DR it's a made up name a for a solvate created because they used hard liquor making it ;)

And I dunno why bother with citing some artificial stupidity.

@Mithoron That question and its answer don't say why other drugs aren't associated with hyclate

Why should they? But yeah, it's not exactly a duplicate.

@Mithoron Why shouldn't they?
